# echoing JavaScript and using PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript

What I want do is `echo` some JavaScript and use PHP variables in the JavaScript code I'm echoing.

Here's what i have tried so far.

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = $output;</script>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = '$output';</script>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = ".$output.";</script>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = '.$output.';</script>";
echo '<script>document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "$output";</script>';
echo "<script>document.getElementById('1').innerHTML =".'$output'.";</script>";
```

I'm out of ideas, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Doing random things in programming very rarely leads to the expected result. At first, do you realize what you want to see as a result? Show the expected result string here.

Comment: Do you realize what my question is? All i asked is how to use a PHP variable in there. The result is irrelevant because my script works if i remove the PHP variable and replace it by a string.

Comment: Just a side note you really should not mix Javascript with PHP like this...

Comment: @Frederic Daniel: I do realize what your question is about. And you don't realize what the result should be, thus you're trying something random things. It doesn't work in programming. Anyway, we don't care - there are tons of lazy people like you here who cannot program and don't even want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just (ab)use `json_encode()`; it works pretty well on strings too:

```
?>
<script>
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($output); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = '".$output."'</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = "<?php echo $output ?>";
</script>
```